# Transform with sum of values of the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:-

```
traffic_type    date        unique_visitors         region   total_views
desktop         01/04/2018  72                      aug      50
mobileweb       01/04/2018  1                       aug      60
total           01/04/2018  sum(mobileweb+desktop)  aug      100
desktop         01/04/2018  75848907.6              world    20
mobileweb       01/04/2018  105737747.4             world    30
total           01/04/2018  sum(mobileweb+desktop)  world    40
```

This might be a duplicate so any link to similar questions will also help and i can 
build the script on similar lines.
As you can see the data i need to fill in the column of unique_visitors is sum of desktop and mobile
provided they are in same region and same date. Dataframe i need

```
traffic_type    date        unique_visitors region  total_views
desktop         01/04/2018  72              aug     50
mobileweb       01/04/2018  1               aug     60
total           01/04/2018  73              aug     100
desktop         01/04/2018  75848907.6      world   20
mobileweb       01/04/2018  105737747.4     world   30
total           01/04/2018  181,586,655     world   40
```

Again I am sorry if this is duplicated i am looking reference links if not the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Create a new df that excludes the text row. Then change to numeric format with `pd.to_numeric` and `.groupby` region to get the `.sum()`. Create a new 'traffic type' column in this dataframe and set to 'total', so that you are now ready to `pd.merge` on multiple columns the summed values back into the dataframe. Then, use `np.where` logic to update the values, and drop the unneeded helper column for the final result.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df1 = df.copy().loc[df['unique_visitors'] != '']
df1['unique_visitors'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['unique_visitors'])
df1 = df1.groupby('region')['unique_visitors'].sum().reset_index()
df1['traffic_type'] = 'total'
df2=pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on=['traffic_type', 'region'], suffixes=('', '_y'))
df2['unique_visitors'] = np.where((df2['traffic_type'] == 'total'),
                                 df2['unique_visitors_y'],
                                 df2['unique_visitors'])
df2 = df2.drop('unique_visitors_y', axis=1)
df2
```

Comment: The text I put was for the reference to show what i need. Any ways I can check for empty data instead of sum(mobileweb+desktop) right?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele I just edited the answer. Yes, you can filter out blanks with my new code.

Comment: if someone is looking for a one-liner here is what i did,

df.loc[df.unique_visitors.isnull(), 'unique_visitors'] = df.groupby(['date', 'region']).unique_visitors.transform('sum')

Answer (score 3):

You can use go row by row and check and sum as below

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["desktop","01/04/2018",72,"aug",50],
                ["mobileweb","01/04/2018",1,"aug",60],
                ["total","01/04/2018","","aug",100],
                ["desktop","01/04/2018",75848907.6 ,"world",20],
                ["mobileweb","01/04/2018",105737747.4,"world",30],
                ["total","01/04/2018","","world",40]],
                columns=["traffic_type","date","unique_visitors","region","total_views"])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["unique_visitors"] == "":
        df.at[index,"unique_visitors"] = df.loc[(df['date'] == row["date"]) & (df["region"] == row["region"]) & (df["unique_visitors"] != ""), 'unique_visitors'].sum()

print(df)
```

### Output

```sh
 traffic_type        date unique_visitors region  total_views
0      desktop  01/04/2018              72    aug           50
1    mobileweb  01/04/2018               1    aug           60
2        total  01/04/2018              73    aug          100
3      desktop  01/04/2018     7.58489e+07  world           20
4    mobileweb  01/04/2018     1.05738e+08  world           30
5        total  01/04/2018     1.81587e+08  world           40
```

for final answer, you should go row by row and add these rows to your original dataset.

Comment: as you can see I dont need the sum of total views. In fact all other columns remain the same.

Comment: while changing data, you can ignore `total_views`

Comment: also the unique visitors for all the columns become 73 i would like to keep them as separate for the different traffic_type

Comment: I changed answer to new one. Please check.

Comment: this works too thank you for your answer and alternate solution.

Comment: if someone is looking for a one-liner here is what i did,

df.loc[df.unique_visitors.isnull(), 'unique_visitors'] = df.groupby(['date', 'region']).unique_visitors.transform('sum')